# How can I echo previous and next page link names in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this wonderful bit of code created by [jackreichert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510734/jackreichert).

This in the `functions.php` file.

```
function siblings($link) {
    global $post;
    $siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
    foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
        if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
            $ID = $key;
        }
    }
    $closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));

    if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') {
        echo $closest[$link];
    }
    else
    {
        return $closest;
    }
}
```

and this on the template page

```
<?php siblings('before'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php siblings('after'); ?>
```

It works wonderfully, but to the echo I would like to be able to add the name of the link as well. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));
```

To:

```
$closest = array('before'=> '<a href="'.get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID).'">'.get_the_title($siblings[$ID-1]->ID).'</a>','after'=> '<a href="'.get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID).'">'.get_the_title($siblings[$ID+1]->ID).'</a>');
```

Comment: excellent!!!!!!!! Thanks, do you by any chance know how to get the links to loop around? so the last link will show the next link as the first? Thanks!!!!

Comment: I'd check this plugin, think it has that functionality. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page-not-next-post/

Comment: yeah tried it but its a bit glitchy as it doesn't respect the menu order

Comment: I don't think your code above does either though, it just removes or adds one to the ID, so doesn't take into account the order?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly at the moment, touch wood! Just wondering how to be able to make it loop